# ios there is a way to do removeobjectsforkeys programmatically for multiple keys

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Any of you knows how can use removeobjectsforkeys programmatically to remove one of more keyvalue pairs from nsarray of dictionaries.

Lets say I have this array of dictionaries:

```
myArray=
myList1
{
    gender = @"male"
    id = 11231
    name = @"John doe"
    picture = @"n/a"
    state = @"CA"
    city = @"Los Angeles"
}
myList1
{
    gender = @"female"
    id = 13123123
    name = @"Teresa doe"
    picture = @"n/a"
    state = @"CA"
    city = @"Los Angeles"
}
```

how can use removeobjectsforkeys to remove one or more keys of the dictionaries depending on the request.

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: I suggest to Get NSMutableArrary so you can easily remove or add object in Arrary

Comment: I'm not talking about removing the dictionaries from the array. what I'm talking about is I need gender and state from each dictionary or if I need picture name and state and gender from each dictionary

Comment: Why do you need to remove objects from dictionary then?

Comment: Are dictionaries mutable or immutable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure instead of "remove" you actually mean "get", based on your followup - but then the part about removeobjectsforkeys makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a mutable array of mutable dictionaries, you can delete a key and its object from all elements of the array like this:

```
[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeObjectForKey:) withObject:@"key2"];
```

You can also use the plural version, removeObjectsForKeys:, by passing an array of keys in the withObject: parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here i just put my simple logic with Array Of Dictionary *(both are mutable)*

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayOfDic.count ; i ++)
{
       [[arrayOfDic objectAtIndex:i] removeObjectForKey:@"keyName1"];
       [[arrayOfDic objectAtIndex:i] removeObjectForKey:@"keyName2"];
       .
       .
       .
       [[arrayOfDic objectAtIndex:i] removeObjectForKey:@"keyName_N"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` for the variables:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in myArray) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey: @"city"] isEqualToString:@"Los Angeles"]) {
        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"city"]
    }
}
```

Comment: but how you do it when you don't know the combinations of the request in terms of they keys are need it?

Comment: Can't understand you. What "request" is?